# How to get the pipline start and end time in "Invoke Rest API"?

Tags: azure-devops

I added an "Invoke Rest API" task at the "post deployment condition" of the last job in a pipeline. And I will need to post the pipeline start and end time to a rest API. What's the variables to get these two values?

The default Header generated for the Rest API Post action.

```
{
"Content-Type":"application/json", 
"PlanUrl": "$(system.CollectionUri)", 
"ProjectId": "$(system.TeamProjectId)", 
"HubName": "$(system.HostType)", 
"PlanId": "$(system.PlanId)", 
"JobId": "$(system.JobId)", 
"TimelineId": "$(system.TimelineId)", 
"TaskInstanceId": "$(system.TaskInstanceId)", 
"AuthToken": "$(system.AccessToken)"
}
```

Need to get the pipeline `StartTime` and `EndTime`, as well as the `Status`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it in the powershell task and got the status and startTime through the following script.

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.releaseId)?api-version=5.1"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$test0 = $pipeline.environments.deploySteps.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.job.status

Write-Host $test0

$test1 = $pipeline.environments.deploySteps.releaseDeployPhases.deploymentJobs.job.startTime

Write-Host $test1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How to do the same function for the Builds (CI)? There is no "post deployment condition" for `Builds`.

Comment: I posted a question for Build authentication issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893431/powershell-task-calls-azure-pipeline-rest-api-cannot-get-authentication

Comment: BTW, I put `echo "Bearer ${env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN}"` in the build Powershell task and `${env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN}` is empty.